# Laravel BaseController already in use

Tags: php, laravel

I've got this in my routes file:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1',function($api)
{
    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1'],function($api)
    {
        $api->post('login','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
    });

    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function($api)
    {
        $api->resource('/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\userController');
        $api->post('/authuser','App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\userController@authUser');
    });
});
```

When I try `php artisan api:routes` I receive the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                        
  Cannot use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController because the name is already in use
```

When I comment this:

```
 //$api->post('login','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
```

The error is gone? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try, by replacing

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as CoreController
```

there would be clashing `BaseController`